# Computer hypervisors

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware

I wasn't sure if I should post this here or on stack overflow, but since my question is more about hardware then about software I think this is the better place.

I have a question regarding the emulation of operating systems (A program like VMware). I understand that the modules of this software run in ring0 priority alongside the modules of your main operating system.

How is it possible that the virtual machine software can force the kernel modules of the emulated operating system to operate in a lower priority ring then ring 0? I mean, the emulated software still works perfectly since I can do all the things I can do with a normal machine. But I don't believe the emulated kernel has control over system resources outside the emulator, or does it???

Comment: I think chroot jails are as close as you can get to the kind of native speeds you seem interested in. Personally, I find VMware ESXi (free) to be very efficient.

Comment: Emulators and virtual machines are two different things.  Virtual machines run the same operating systems as physical machines.  You need to rephrase your question with this in mind.  VMware is a company and not a program, so I am not sure which product you are referring to, but in any case, it is not an emulator.

Comment: This is the better place for software questions, too, since this has nothing to do with programming specifically.

Comment: @paradroid, if you host a quest os on top of your main os you must be emulating it right? Or are virtual machines and emulators two different things?

Comment: @Unknown: They are different things.  A virtual machine runs the same operating systems as a physical machine.  It is the virtual machine which emulates hardware and no emulation of any operating system occurs, unlike emulators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I don't believe the emulated kernel has control over system
>   resources outside the emulator, or does it???

Indeed it doesn't. The kernel operates on a new specialized "Ring-1". Above the kernel is the Hypervisor (the program actually responsible for maintaining the virtualization environment and that lives on the host system). That is the one that operates at ring-0 on the host machine. Any guest OS operates in a new isolated Ring-1 created by the hypervisor.

See: [Ring, Computer Security (Hypervisor Mode)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29#Hypervisor_mode)

Comment: I see now, but what if I were running older hardware? Hardware that doesn't support ring-1, or am I talking nonsense right now?

Answer (score 0):

> How is it possible that the virtual machine software can force the
>   kernel modules of the emulated operating system to operate in a lower
>   priority ring then ring 0?

The architecture of modern processors lets a CPU "emulate itself". As far as the guest OS knows, it is actually controlling the hardware, but in reality the hypervisor is intercepting all interrupts, etc. and emulating the responses.